# Adjust UITableViewCell separator line when in multiple edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm looking to adjust the separator inset margin when in multiple edit mode in a standard UITableView in iOS 9/10.

[image]

My goal is to align the separator line with the **left edge of the cell's text label**.

[image]

In the past, I've removed the margins entirely by doing:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.separatorInset = .zero
    cell.layoutMargins = .zero
}
```

That gives me a view such as:

[image]

If I try to increase the separator inset, the entire text label moves over, which I don't want. :

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 0)
```

[image]

How can I just move the separator line, without affecting the text layout, and preferably without doing any overriding of `layoutSubviews` or drawing lines manually?

Comment: Did you ever figured this one out?

Comment: @StianHøiland have you tried the code in the question above before? because it works on my side.

Answer (score 1):

You can add separator manually, try to use below code

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
   let separator = CALayer()

    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();
    separator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 43, self.view.frame.size.width, 1);
    cell.layer.insertSublayer(separator, atIndex:0)
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This would work, but as I said I want to avoid drawing lines manually. Especially in this case, there's no guarantee the width of the checkmark is fixed so subsequent updates could break this method.

Comment: Yes, but setting inset also would not guarantee, I think if checkbox width change in future update you have to change the inset of separator frame accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on xcode 8, with ios 9

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    cell.layoutMargins = .zero
}
```

gives you the what you want as per your third picture.

I've tried

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    cell.layoutMargins = .zero
}
```

it works too, not sure why its not working on your side..